# how to implement ctc loss function for Sequential model in keras

Tags: python, keras, conv-neural-network, lstm

Hi guys i have cnn+lstm keras model and i want to use ctc loss function,there are bunch off solutions around but all of them are very confusing any help will be appreciated.
here is my model:

```
model=Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), input_shape=(28, 28,3), activation='relu'))
model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(32, activation='relu'))
model.add(RepeatVector(25))
model.add(LSTM(128, return_sequences=True, input_shape=(25,32), activation='relu'))
model.add(LSTM(256))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))
model.add(Dense(37))
model.compile(loss='ctc_loss', optimizer='rmsprop')
```

Comment: If you have find any solution, please share with me. I am facing the same problem.

Comment: In my case it was not possible to implement the model in sequential form so i use functional way to do it